# does dropzone-amd-module.js support IE 11?

Tags: requirejs, durandal, dropzone

Per the dropzone site version 5.0 should support IE10+. I am using `dropzone-amd-module.js` ver 5.5 in a Durandal app and IE11 does not seem to support `Symbol.iterator`. Since I need to support IE11 at least for a little while I'm looking for options.  Does any know what the latest version of `dropzone-amd-module.js` is that will run in IE11?

Comment: IE11 does not support Symbol.iterator but the update to dropzone-amd-module.js to convert Symbol.iterator to a conventional for loop was easy and mechanical.          //for (var _iterator2 = this.element.getElementsByTagName("div"), _isArray2 = Array.isArray(_iterator2), _i2 = 0, _iterator2 = _isArray2 ? _iterator2 : _iterator2[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
          for (var _iterator2 = this.element.getElementsByTagName("div"), _isArray2 = true, _i2 = 0; ;) {

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to remove any reference to Symbol.iterator wherever it occurs (a few dozen places) from dropzone-amd-module.js like this:

replace this

```
for (var _iterator2 = this.element.getElementsByTagName("div"), _isArray2 = 
Array.isArray(_iterator2), _i2 = 0, _iterator2 = _isArray2 ? _iterator2 : 
_iterator2[Symbol.iterator]();;) {
```

with this

```
for (var _iterator2 = this.element.getElementsByTagName("div"), _isArray2 = true, _i2 
= 0; ;) {
```